# How to read the first line of a File and compare to what you input in C? I'm new to C and need some support

Tags: c, file, compare

I'm trying to write a table data to a file in C and i just want the first line of the file to stay the same after one input! How can i do this ? Thanks in advance

I have tried many ways but nothing seems to suit what i want.

here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sting.h>
    ỉnt main(){
        FILE *fptr;
        fptr = fopen("text.txt", "r");  
        if(strcmp(fgets("123", 1, fptr),"123")==0){
            fclose(fptr);
        }
        else{
fptr = fopen("text.txt", "r");  
            fprintf(fptr, "123");
            fclose(fptr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome! Please post the code for what you have tried, along with details as to what is expected, and what goes wrong. We usually like to see a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows the problem.

Comment: `strcmp(fgets("123", 1, fptr),"123")` is a double dose of [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior): attempting to write one (`1`) byte to the read-only memory pointed to by the string literal `"123"`, or passing `NULL` to `strcmp` if `fgets` fails. It is still very unclear what you are trying to do, but at the very least you should read some [documentation for `fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

Comment: `fopen("text.txt", "w")` - `"w"` will truncate the file (delete all its contents) every time this program runs, and opens the file for *writing*. Again, reading the [documentation for `fopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) is advised.

Comment: It isn't clear where the program's input is coming from. You are writing to "text.txt", so is the `fgets()` supposed to read from `STDIN` (the keyboard)?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some problems:

- you must include `<stdio.h>` and `<string.h>`
- you should open the file in read mode with `"r"` instead of `"w"`,
- you should use a local array to read the line.
- you should include the trailing newline in the string for comparison

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

ỉnt main() {
    FILE *fptr = fopen("text.txt", "r");  
    if (fptr) {
        char buf[80];
        if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fptr)) {
            if (strcmp(buf, "123\n") == 0) {
                printf("file contains 123\n");
            } else {
                printf("file does not contain 123: %s\n", buf);
            }
        } else {
            printf("file is empty\n");
        }
        fclose(fptr);
    } else {
        printf("cannot open file %s\n", "text.txt");
    }
    return 0;
}
```